# How to delete a button when another button is clicked?

Tags: c#, forms

It's probably quite trivial, but my problem is I need to delete two buttons when one of them is clicked. At the moment, my code will create these two buttons when a third is clicked. What I want is for one of these options to do something (this I have done) and, once complete, make these buttons disappear again. Here is the code to create two buttons:

```
private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button d = new Button();
    Button c = new Button();
    d.Text = "Dice";
    c.Text = "Chance Card";
    d.Name = "btnDice";
    c.Name = "btnCC";
    d.Location = new Point(btnRandom.Location.X, btnRandom.Location.Y + 30);
    c.Location = new Point(btnRandom.Location.X, btnRandom.Location.Y + 60);
    d.Click += new EventHandler(d_Click);
    c.Click += new EventHandler(c_Click);            
    this.Controls.Add(d);
    this.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

And below is my failed attempt at removing this button

```
private void d_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     this.Controls.Remove(btnDice); // This doesnt work
}
```

Comment: You could make the button invisible: btnDice.Visible = false;

Comment: dang you were first. But indeed, try to make it invisible

Comment: and to make it visible again: btnDice.Visible = true?

Comment: have you tried my answer below ?

Comment: Thanks all - I didn't realize invisible was a thing, and probably would not have thought of it anyway. Sorted now :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you code is OK, but you need to re-paint the form after removing the control.

```
this.Controls.Remove(btnDice);
this.Refresh();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button using

```
this.btnDice.Enabled = false;
```

or you can use visible property to hide it
e.g.

```
this.btnDice.Visible = false;
```

For removing You might need to refresh the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by removing the `sender` :

```
private void d_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.Controls.Remove((Button)(sender));
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the button disappear and reappear again ?

```
//Make the button disappear
this.btnDice.Visible = false;

//Make the button reappear
this.btnDice.Visible = true;
```